# Dojo - Digit Select get selected text quirks

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a dijit.form.select with some option's **values** being the same (and I can't change them so that they are different). I think this may be the cause of some quirks in the behavior. For example, when I have a select like this:

```
<select id="deptSelector" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select">
    <option value="someuser@gmail.com">Childcare Department</option>
    <option value="someuser2@gmail.com">Health Goods Department</option>
    <option value="someuser2@gmail.com">Medicine Department</option>
    <option value="someuser3@gmail.com">Customer Service</option>
    <option value="someuser2@gmail.com">Other department</option> 
</select>
```

Some of the values are the same, but their labels need to be different. However, when I call

```
dijit.byId(this.namespace+'deptSelector').attr('displayedValue');
```

(which I read was the way to get the label for the select), for some reason, it just keeps getting me the first option in the select with the same value. For example, if I select "Other Department", it will give me "Health Goods Department". I don't see why this is happening because I thought it was just supposed to get the DISPLAYED value, not base the result off of the value of the selected item.

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there anything different I could do to get the right label without changing the values?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of dojo?  looks like 1.6 from your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dijit.byId(this.namespace+'deptSelector').focusedChild.label
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest separating the data from the html by using a store instead. You could do something like :

Html :

```
<select id="deptSelector"></select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
require(['dijit/form/Select',
    'dijit/registry',
    'dojo/html',
    'dojo/store/Memory',
    'dojo/domReady!'], function (Select, registry, html, Memory) {

    var departments = new Memory({
        data: [{
            id : 1,
            name: "Childcare Department",
            email: "someuser@gmail.com"
        }, {
            id : 2,
            name: "Health Goods Department",
            email: "someuser2@gmail.com"
        }, {
            id : 3,
            name: "Medicine Department",
            email: "someuser2@gmail.com"
        }, {
            id : 4,
            name: "Customer Service",
            email: "someuser3@gmail.com"
        }, {
            id : 5,
            name: "Other Department",
            email: "someuser2@gmail.com"
        }]
    }),
    deptSelector = new Select({
        store: departments,
        labelAttr : 'name'
    }, 'deptSelector');

    deptSelector.on('change', function (value) {
        html.set('output', departments.get(deptSelector.get('value')).email);
    });

    deptSelector.startup();

    html.set('output', departments.get(deptSelector.get('value')).email);

});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/kzWdV/

Answer (score 0):

var label = registry.byId("deptSelector").get("displayedValue");

registry comes from dijit/registry.